# Are there any tools/methods to probe a web app from diffferent IPs?

Tags: penetration-test, network-scanners

I am currently reading "Metasploit: The Penetration Tester's Guide" and I came across the following paragraph in the book (in the 1st  chapter)

> During intelligence gathering, you attempt to identify what protection
>   mechanisms are in place at the target by slowly starting to probe its
>   systems. For example, an organization will often only allow traffic on
>   a certain subset of ports on externally facing devices, and if you
>   query the organization on any- thing other than a whitelisted port,
>   you will be blocked. It is generally a good idea to test this blocking
>   behavior by initially probing from an expendable IP address that you
>   are willing to have blocked or detected. The same holds true when
>   you’re testing web applications, where, after a certain threshold, the
>   web application firewalls will block you from making further requests.

I can imagine doing this using the Tor network or may be a proxy (or may be a bot  network, provided you have one :-P ) but honestly, I am not aware of any tools by which I could scan a web app, and if I get blocked, I could generate a new IP and do the scan again.  Are there any tools/methods which let me do so. Please pardon my lack of knowledge, it really feels like a foolish question but I don't know if such tools/methods exist.

Comment: Sorry for lack of real answer, just wanna drop this here: http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read the book, and I also have a good [example](http://addaxsoft.com/wp-admin) of a web app blocking traffic from certain IPs ..

You can spoof your source IP address the way you want but you won't get any response because once the forged TCP/UDP packet reaches your target (assuming it makes it through firewalls) the reply will be sent to that **FORGED** IP address and it will never reach you.

You will have better results using **TOR** as you mentioned!